# Documentation on Apple's USB Chargers?

Tags: power-supply, usb, battery-charging

I'm worried if someone charges my single-cell lipo with an Apple USB power supply that it'll get damaged.

***Is there documentation on Apple's USB chargers?***

I'm imagining I want to be able to support old apple chargers as well, so well-managed documentation on all the different ones out there and their versions would be nice (e.g. iPhone, iPad, other ones...).  Haven't found anything yet.  Is this just something people hack to find out and Apple never officially tells anyone what they do?

Comment: If you protect is properly, why worry? You do have over current and reverse polarity protection as a minimum, right?

Comment: short answer seems to be that Apple does NOT manage nor provide any documentation.  i don't understand the downvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "chargers" are just 5V switchmode power supplies.

They have a bit of a trick (resistors on the otherwise unused USB data lines) that allows the unit plugged into the supply to know the current capability, but the charging circuitry itself is built into the device with the battery.

If you're concerned about drawing excessive current from the supply, you could limit yourself to the smallest charger's capability, detect the Apple resistors, or implement a more general solution. This chip may be of interest: [MAX14617](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14617.pdf), which emulates adapters (including Apple adapters) and thus has the information required to specify the design of circuitry to detect the adapter emulation.

[Here](https://learn.adafruit.com/minty-boost/icharging) is some hacker-level reverse engineering that should give you the idea. This limits an iPhone to 0.5A charging:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the 2 data lines are taken to the + via a resistor and to the - via another resistor. The values of the resistors I cannot tell you but they are there to tell the charger to power at maximum and thus charge the batteries much faster. A voltage is detected by the charger to give full charge and if not there to give just 0.5v i.e. trickle charge.
Try searching for 'making charger cable for iPhone'.
Have a look at this and read the comments at the end
http://www.instructables.com/id/Iphone-usb-chargerwire-hack/

Hope this helps.